# How do I block javascript for all subdomains of example.com?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, javascript

Hi all I have set my browser to disable javascript for http://en.wikipedia.org.

[image]

I was wondering How do I block javascript for all sub-domains of the host wikipedia.org ?

(I would like to block javascript for the pages `*.wikipedia.org`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*.]wikipedia.org should do the trick.

Comment: @@Ravachol Brilliant!

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just add `*.wikipedia.org` as a **Hostname Pattern** and set **Behavior** action to `Block`?

Comment: It doesn't allow the character `*`